# Looping through 2 dataframes and take mode of specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops, nested, mode

Given is df1 (which contains most and least sold products of each shop):

```
id   most_sold_A  most_sold_B  most_sold_C  least_sold_A  least_sold_B  least_sold_C
1     1             0           0             0            1             1
2     0             1           0             1            0             0
3     0             1           1             1            0             0
```

and df2 (which contains the distance between 2 shops) is also given:

```
id1   id2   distance 
1     2      0.5
1     3      3.0
2     3      0.2
```

The resulting dataframe should

1. check which shop_ids are within 1k distance of each shopid
2. take the mode of the most_sold_product over all competitors within 1k
3. take the mode of the least_sold_product over all competitors within 1k

resulting df:

```
id   most_sold_A  most_sold_B  most_sold_C  least_sold_A  least_sold_B  least_sold_C    /
1     1             0           0             0            1             1
2     0             1           0             1            0             0
3     0             1           1             1            0             0

most_sold_competition_within_1k   least_sold_competition_within_1k
B                                    A
[A,B,C]                              [A,B,C]
B                                    A
```

**EDIT**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,0,0,0,1,1],
[2,0,1,0,1,0,0],
[3,0,1,1,1,0,0]],columns = ["id","most_sold_A","most_sold_B","most_sold_C","least_sold_A","least_sold_B","least_sold_C"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,0.5],
[1,3,3.0],
[2,3,0.2]], columns = ["id1","id2","distance"])
```

Comment: Why does [A,B,C]  is in `most_sold_competition_within_1k`? If i've understood you're problem, it should be [A,C], isn't it?

Comment: It should be [A,B,C] as shop 2 has 2 competitors within 1k namely shop 1 and shop 3. As shop 1 most sold products are A and shop 3 most sold products are B and C. Since A, B, C each have thus frequency 1 they should all be returned as competitors most sold products. Same for least sold products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the "tricky" part is finding the relevant competitors for each shop. I'm sure there are more elegent solutions, but a straight-forward one is:

```py
def find_competitors(x, df2):
    shops = np.unique(df2[(df2.id1==x.id) | (df2.id2 == x.id)][['id1','id2']])
    competitors = np.delete(shops, np.argwhere(shops == x.id))
    return competitors

df2 = df2[df2.distance<=1]
df1['competitors'] = df1.apply(lambda x: find_competitors(x, df2),axis=1)
```

Now, for each shop, you now it's relevant competitors, and you can find the answer for your 2 other questions (most sold and least sold products of competitors), by simply iterating over each shop's competitor. I hope that was clear enough.

**UPDATE**

In order to find the competitors least/most products, you can use:

```py
most_cols = [col for col in df1.columns if 'most' in col]

def find_competitors_by_metric(x, metric_cols):
    competitors_metric = df1[df1.id.isin(x.competitors)][metric_cols]
    return competitors_metric.T[competitors_metric.any()].T.columns

most_for_competitors = df1.apply(lambda x: find_competitors_by_metric(x,most_cols),axis=1)
```

Now you can send that function which metrics you want to compute for the competitors of the shop (assuming those metrics exist in the dataframe).

Comment: This indeed works thank you! But do you have an efficient way to find the mode of the most/least sold products of competitors?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a not-so-efficient solution, I suggest to start with this one and profile it if you'll need to optimize it.

Comment: Thank you! So the most_for_competitors series returns for each shop a list with the most_sold products of the its competitors, do I understand correctly? The code works great, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, you have understood correctly. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

I came out with something, but I think it can be further optimized. The idea would be to first filter the competitors in range, then join and then compute the result with an `.apply()`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,0,0,0,1,1],
[2,0,1,0,1,0,0],
[3,0,1,1,1,0,0]],columns = ["id","most_sold_A","most_sold_B","most_sold_C","least_sold_A","least_sold_B","least_sold_C"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,0.5],
[1,3,3.0],
[2,3,0.2]], columns = ["id1","id2","distance"])

df2 = pd.concat([df2,df2[["id2","id1","distance"]].rename(columns = {"id2":"id1","id1":"id2"})]).reset_index()[["id1","id2","distance"]]
df2["id2"] = df2["id2"].astype(str)
df2 = df2[df2["distance"]<1][["id1","id2"]].groupby("id1").agg({'id2': ','.join}).reset_index()

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how = 'left',left_on="id", right_on="id1")

most_cols = [col for col in df3.columns if 'most' in col]
least_cols = [col for col in df3.columns if 'least' in col]

df3["most_sold_competition_within_1k"] = df3.apply(lambda x: [df3[df3["id"]==int(elem)][most_cols].columns[[df3[df3["id"]==int(elem)][most_cols].values == 1][0][0]] for elem in x["id2"].split(",")],axis = 1)
df3["least_sold_competition_within_1k"] = df3.apply(lambda x: [df3[df3["id"]==int(elem)][least_cols].columns[[df3[df3["id"]==int(elem)][least_cols].values == 1][0][0]] for elem in x["id2"].split(",")],axis = 1)

df3 = df3[["id"]+most_cols+least_cols+["most_sold_competition_within_1k","least_sold_competition_within_1k"]]

df3
```

Output:

```
    id  most_sold_A most_sold_B most_sold_C least_sold_A    least_sold_B    least_sold_C    most_sold_competition_within_1k   least_sold_competition_within_1k
0   1   1           0           0           0               1               1              [[most_sold_B]]              [[least_sold_A]]
1   2   0           1           0           1               0               0    [[most_sold_B, most_sold_C], [most_sold_A]  [[least_sold_A], [least_sold_B, least_sold_C]]
2   3   0           1           1           1               0               0      [[most_sold_B]]                            [[least_sold_A]]
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work till line      df3["most_sold_competition_within_1k"] = df3.apply(lambda x: [df3[df3["id"]==int(elem)][most_cols].columns[[df3[df3["id"]==int(elem)][most_cols].values == 1][0][0]] for elem in x["id2"].split(",")],axis = 1) where it throws the error index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: You mean as it is or with you own dataframe? If it is with your own dataframe, you have to check all ids has another one within less than 1k, otherwise won't work for some cases. Same case for ids that do not have some item (most and least sold) equal 1.  You need to somehow remove those cases.

Comment: With my own dataframe. Indeed I think that is the problem. Even though the functions above are more efficient, this code might work fine as well. Thank for your help!